# Using jquery to load page on scroll down

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I'm getting the List of objects to **JSP** and iterating them using `<foreach>` **JSTL** tag to display the values on the page.
Now, i wanted to provide the scroll down to display data functionality.

I want to display the first 10 elements first and on scrolling displaying another 10 elements. Can you guys help me or suggest me another logic to implement

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Infinite scroll](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/07/infinite-scroll-loading-content-while-scrolling-using-java-and-jquery/) (example using jsp & jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The example is looking good. But my JSP is getting list of objects from the database. What would be the best way to achieve this. Do I need to hit the database to get the 10 objects each time or is there any way so that I can hit the database once to get all the objects at a time and can I apply this scrolling?

Comment: You will need to get 10 objects from the db each time

Comment: Is it best practice to do like this ? Because we need to make 10 database calls for fetching 100 objects.

Comment: You can use caching of the data and fetch it every time: http://distributedcaching.blog.com/2012/04/06/improve-javaserver-pages-performance-with-caching/